# Why is this SQL function working differently within an insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting a primary key violation in the column 'voorwerpnummer'. The duplicate value is 1, but the function should never give the same number twice. When I try testing the function without anything in the 'Voorwerp' table, it returns 1, and if I test it with one row in the 'Voorwerp' table it returns 2; like it should. Why is it returning 1 twice within this insert query? I'm using SQL Server 2016.

```
-- Empty tables
DELETE
FROM Bestand

DELETE
FROM Voorwerp_in_rubriek

DELETE
FROM Voorwerp

-- Delete function if exists
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   sys.objects
           WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[GetVoorwerpnummer]')
                  AND type IN ( N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT' ))
  DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetVoorwerpnummer]
GO 

-- Returns the next item number
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetVoorwerpnummer()
RETURNS INTEGER
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Highest INTEGER
    -- Find the highest number
    SET @Highest = (SELECT TOP 1 voorwerpnummer FROM EenmaalAndermaal.dbo.Voorwerp ORDER BY voorwerpnummer DESC)
    -- Take 0 if there is none
    SET @Highest = ISNULL(@Highest, 0)
    -- Add 1
    SET @Highest = (@Highest + 1);

    RETURN @Highest
END
GO

INSERT INTO EenmaalAndermaal.dbo.Voorwerp (looptijd, looptijdbegin, startprijs, verzendkosten, verkoopprijs, beschrijving, betalingsinstructie, betalingswijzenaam, landnaam, plaatsnaam, titel, verzendinstructies, voorwerpnummer, wel_niet_indicator, verkoper, koper)
    SELECT  
            10 AS looptijd,
            GETDATE() AS looptijdbegin,
            LEFT(Prijs,8) AS startprijs,
            '1,20' AS verzendkosten,
            NULL AS verkoopprijs,
            'Beschrijving van product' AS beschrijving,
            NULL AS betalingsinstructie,
            'paypal' AS betalingswijzenaam,
            LEFT(land,40) AS landnaam,
            LEFT(Locatie,40) AS plaatsnaam,
            LEFT(Titel,40) AS titel,
            NULL AS verzendinstructies,
            dbo.GetVoorwerpnummer() AS voorwerpnummer,
            0 AS wel_niet_indicator,
            LEFT(Verkoper, 40) AS Verkoper,
            NULL AS koper
    FROM EBAY.dbo.Items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because SQL works set-based, not row-based.

The `SELECT` statement is executed first. That results in a data set, all with the same `voorwerpnummer` (since nothing has been added to `EenmaalAndermaal.dbo.Voorwerp` yet). You can test this by executing just the `SELECT` statement. That entire set is than `INSERT`ed into your target table, so a subsequent call to `GetVoorwerpnummer()` will result in a higher `voorwerpnummer` (obviously if the `INSERT` would be successful, which it won't be if `voorwerpnummer` is the PK).

To correct it, I would do the following:

```
-- Execute function once to fill variable, so it isn't needlessly executed for every row
DECLARE @Voorwerp INT = dbo.GetVoorwerpnummer();

INSERT INTO EenmaalAndermaal.dbo.Voorwerp (looptijd, looptijdbegin, startprijs, verzendkosten, verkoopprijs, beschrijving, betalingsinstructie, betalingswijzenaam, landnaam, plaatsnaam, titel, verzendinstructies, voorwerpnummer, wel_niet_indicator, verkoper, koper)
    SELECT  
            10 AS looptijd,
            GETDATE() AS looptijdbegin,
            LEFT(Prijs,8) AS startprijs,
            '1,20' AS verzendkosten,
            NULL AS verkoopprijs,
            'Beschrijving van product' AS beschrijving,
            NULL AS betalingsinstructie,
            'paypal' AS betalingswijzenaam,
            LEFT(land,40) AS landnaam,
            LEFT(Locatie,40) AS plaatsnaam,
            LEFT(Titel,40) AS titel,
            NULL AS verzendinstructies,
            COALESCE(@Voorwerp, 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id /*Choose a logical, preferably unique column here*/) AS voorwerpnummer,
            0 AS wel_niet_indicator,
            LEFT(Verkoper, 40) AS Verkoper,
            NULL AS koper
    FROM EBAY.dbo.Items
```

As Stilgar below commented, it is better to define the PK as an `IDENTITY` attribute.

Also, personally (I'm not sure if it's 'official' best practices), I prefer to keep my Primary Key columns as first columns of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely a matter of not committing the INSERT; until committed, the data doesn't "really" exist.

The following works for me:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.PK_Test
    (
     PK         INT
    ,TXT        VARCHAR(0032)
    );

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO dbo.PK_Test VALUES(05, 'First');
COMMIT TRANSACTION;


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_PK_Test()
RETURNS INTEGER
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Highest INTEGER
    -- Find the highest number
    SET @Highest = (SELECT TOP 1 PK FROM PK_Test ORDER BY PK DESC)
    -- Take 0 if there is none
    SET @Highest = ISNULL(@Highest, 0)
    -- Add 1
    SET @Highest = (@Highest + 1);

    RETURN @Highest
END;

SELECT * FROM dbo.PK_Test;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Adhoc_Area.dbo.PK_Test (PK, Txt) VALUES (Adhoc_Area.dbo.F_PK_Test(), Adhoc_Area.dbo.F_PK_Test());
    INSERT INTO Adhoc_Area.dbo.PK_Test (PK, Txt) VALUES (Adhoc_Area.dbo.F_PK_Test(), Adhoc_Area.dbo.F_PK_Test());
COMMIT TRANSACTION;


SELECT * FROM dbo.PK_Test;
```

Comment: What happens if you insert a set (multiple records), rather than a single record at a time? eg: `INSERT INTO tmp.PK_Test
 SELECT dbo.F_PK_Test(), ''
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T`

Comment: Then it would break, I missed the FROM part of that which makes it a set operation.  Totally my bad.  So question now would be why not use IDENTITY instead of managing unique sequential number manually?

Comment: I thought about that, but if it's possible I'd rather not make any changes to the tables.

Comment: Perhaps SEQUENCE?